# card deck flip not working in old browser

Tags: internet-explorer-11

Have not tried to build flip cards before but very new to CSS so I am struggling to amend code found online to what I need and to then get it to work on IE, can someone please point me in the right direction?

Please no Javascript answers, I have no idea how to use Javascript yet, and I am stuck with having to find a way to make this work for IE as large proportion of client base still uses it

Thank you in advance!

HTML:

```
   <div class="flip-card-wrapper">
    <div class="flip-card-container">
        <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-front">Gender</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back">Text</div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="flip-card-container">
        <div class="flip-card">
            <div class="flip-card-front">Families Network</div>
            <div class="flip-card-back"><p>Text</p></div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.flip-card-wrapper {
    width: 840px;
    height: 400px;
}

.flip-card-container {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    perspective:1000px;
    float: left;
}

.flip-card-container:hover .flip-card {
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    transition: transform 1s;
    float: left;
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
    background-color:#333;
    color:#fff
}

.flip-card-back {
    background-color:#517fa4;
    color:#fff;
    transform:rotateY(180deg);
}
```

Comment: Does the code example help you to fix the flip card issue for the IE browser? If yes, you can try to accept the answer. It can help other community members in the future in similar kinds of issues. Thanks for your understanding. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you refer to the example below may help you to achieve the flip card effect for the IE 11 browser, also it works fine with latest browsers.

```css
/* entire container, keeps perspective */
.flip-container {
    perspective: 1000;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}
    /*  UPDATED! flip the pane when hovered */
    .flip-container:hover .back {
        transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    .flip-container:hover .front {
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }

.flip-container, .front, .back {
    width: 320px;
    height: 480px;
}

/* flip speed goes here */
.flipper {
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: relative;
}

/* hide back of pane during swap */
.front, .back {
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    transition: 0.6s;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

/*  UPDATED! front pane, placed above back */
.front {
    z-index: 2;
    transform: rotateY(0deg);
    background: lightgreen;
}

/* back, initially hidden pane */
.back {
    transform: rotateY(-180deg);
    background: lightblue;
}

/* 
    Some vertical flip updates 
*/
.vertical.flip-container {
    position: relative;
}

    .vertical .back {
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }

    .vertical.flip-container:hover .back {
        transform: rotateX(0deg);
    }

    .vertical.flip-container:hover .front {
        transform: rotateX(180deg);
    }
```

```html
<div class="flip-container">
        <div class="flipper">
            <div class="front">
                front
            </div>
            <div class="back">
                back
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Output in the IE 11 browser:

[image]

Reference:

[CSS Flip animation example](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/rebaLo16/)

Further, you can try to modify the example as per your own requirements.